# Rpi Python 1-Wire File System to read DS2482 I2C to 1-Wire bridge connected DS18B20 Temperature Sensors

Tags: python, i2c, ds18b20, 1-wire

I'm currently working on the project with a lot of [DS18B20 Digital Thermometer Sensors](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf). For a better performance I decided to use this Raspberry Pi compatible [1-wire master board](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Rs-Pi-i2c-1-Wire-8-channel-8-bus-Board-for-Raspberry-Pi-A-B-B-/221599231161?hash=item339857ecb9:g:picAAOSwrx5UXjzt), which is based on the [DS2482-800](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2482-800.pdf) IC with 8 individual 1-wire channels. Since Raspberry Pi has just one 1-wire channel and the DS2482 chip speaks via I2C protocol to the Raspberry Pi, I'm hoping to read out the temperature data faster.

Following [this tutorial](https://wiki.m.nu/index.php/OWFS_with_i2c_support_on_Raspberry_Pi_(English_version)) I finally managed to start the owfs with:

```
sudo /opt/owfs/bin/owfs --i2c=ALL:ALL --allow_other /mnt/1wire/
```

and read out the temperature data like this:

[image]

Showing me the current temperature of 22.4375 °C.

One way of reading the data with python could be something like:

```
with open('mnt/1wire/28.6613DA050000/temperature') as infile:
     temp_data = infile.read()
```

But I would prefer using the [OWFS python package](http://owfs.sourceforge.net/owpython.html).

There is [some information about how to use it](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/3/owfs-with-i2c-support-on-raspberry-pi), so I came up with this script:

```
import ow
ow.init('localhost:4304')
sensorlist = ow.Sensor('/').sensorList()
for sensor in sensorlist:
    print('Device Found')
    print('Address: ' + sensor.address)
    print('Family: ' + sensor.family)
    print('ID: ' + sensor.id)
    print('Type: ' + sensor.type)
    print(' ')
```

Running it returns the error:

```
1487688470 DEFAULT: ow_parsename.c:(316) debug_crash 1487688470.956012
Segmentation fault
```

If I insert any specific sensor to upper code like this:

```
sensorlist = ow.Sensor('/mnt/1wire/28.6613DA050000').sensorList()
```

it returns:

```
ow.exUnknownSensor: '/mnt/1wire/28.6613DA050000/type'
```

even though there is a file `/mnt/1wire/28.6613DA050000/type` containing the following text:

```
DS18B20
```

... Any idea of how to use the python-ow package? Am I missing something? Do I have to point to the owfs mountpoint at `/mnt/1wire/` in the python script somehow?

Comment: Ok once my owfsserver is running via: `sudo /opt/owfs/bin/owserver /etc/owfs.conf --i2c=/dev/i2c-1 -p 4304` I managed to get [pyownet](http://pyownet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) running. This library is doing a great job reading the owfs sensor data.

Comment: here's nothing wrong with posting an answer yourself and accepting it. It helps others looking for answers in the future when they search and find this has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in a comment:
The owfs server needs to be started with the following command:

```
sudo /opt/owfs/bin/owserver /etc/owfs.conf --i2c=/dev/i2c-1 -p 4304
```

Doing so it is possible to read out the temperature data with the pyownet library, like [described in the docu](http://pyownet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol.html).

However I did not manage to speedup the readout of many sensors this way. For speeding up the readout process of many sensors I decided to use the python [threading library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html) to parallelize the 'analog-to-digital data conversion' process in each and every sensor.